# Creating various repeated actions scenario

Tags: loadrunner

I am using LoadRunner, could anyone advise me on how to create below test scenarios using LoadRunner action and Controller ?  Thanks in advance.

- 120 concurrent user login within 1 hour (to test for 1 hour steady state)
- Total 450 Web form actions triggered by 120 users within 1 hour as breakdown below, i.e. after user login, then trigger WebFormA, WebFormB and WebFormC action (sequence not important).
- Each user triggers 4 web forms within 1 hour, 15min per form (transaction time + think time)

WebFormLogin action: 120

WebFormA action: 100

WebFormB action: 180

WebFormC action: 200

(i.e. Total 480 web form actions triggered after login)

Thanks,
Leanne

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the HTTP logs:

- How many Login Pages requests are made per hour?
- If you count how many forms each distinct IP address/user session takes advantage of what is that number?
- What is the duration of the session, from the first request to the last request by IP address?
- Once you know your session duration, if you block your high volume hour by the session length, how many distinct IP addresses/Session tokens are present within a session length block?  Measures user concurrency at Max, Min and Average session lengths )

Once you understand from an examination of the logs what your natural user level of concurrency is and how many forms your natural user executes, including potentially patterns/sequences associated forms, then you have information which can be used for your load profile.

Your user concurrency on session duration speaks to the number of users involves in your test.  I tend to use a value of 95% session duration for planning purposes for my session block size.   Your session duration provides for your iteration pacing interval in your run time settings.   Your observed patters of behavior directly leads to your development of virtual users, independent of tool.

If your users only execute one web form and then depart, then you will be building each of your web forms as singletons and staging the users in proportion to the number of forms of each type that have to be hit per hour.  If, on the other hand, your users engage in multiple forms per session then you are looking at development which attempts to replicate some of the complexity by starting with form A then branching to other forms based upon observed population behavior.   The closer you get to the natural population behavior then the better a predictor your test is likely to be.